# programmatically find and replace content dynamically in a string in python

Tags: python, replace

i need to find and replace patterns in a string with a dynamically generated content.

lets say i want to find all strings within '' in the string and double the string. 
a string like:

`my 'cat' is 'white'` should become my `'catcat' is 'whitewhite'`

all matches could also appear twice in the string.

thank you

Comment: Let's just hope the string isn't XML, and those quotes aren't XML open and close tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make use of the power of [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). In this particular case:

```
import re

s = "my 'cat' is 'white'"

print re.sub("'([^']+)'", r"'\1\1'", s) # prints my 'catcat' is 'whitewhite'
```

`\1` refers to the first group in the regex (called `$1` in some other implementations).

Comment: thank you. to extend this i found out i can define a function before the re.sub and apply it to the replace argument without calling it and passing the matchobject.

Answer (score 1):

It's also pretty easy to do it without regex in your case:

```
s = "my 'cat' is 'white'".split("'")
# the parts between the ' are at the 1, 3, 5 .. index 
print s[1::2]
# replace them with new elements
s[1::2] = [x+x for x in s[1::2]]
# join that stuff back together
print "'".join(s)
```

Comment: @aschmid00: That gives "'whitewhite' is my 'catcat'"  ... as expected, or not?

Comment: yes ur right but still not a pretty solution in my point of view.